# Convert object list to set of a field

Tags: java, java-stream

The object class is

```
Car{ 
public long id;
String name;
...
public String getAttribute(String attrName){
  if(attrName.equals("NAME"))
    return name;
  //...
}
  // ...
}
```

Now, I have a list.

```
List<Car> inventory;
```

Now i want to get a set of names

```
Set<String>
```

I'm not sure how...

Until now i got

```
inventory.stream()...collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

What to use in place of ... So that i get list of names?

Comment: `Set<Long> ids = inventory.stream().map(Car::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Comment: Set<String> names = inventory.stream().map(Car::getName).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Comment: I don't have a getName method, i need to get using a getAttribute ("NAME") method

Answer (score 2):

Map and call the function

`map(Car::getId)`